# I don't know why the test fails. feat JUnit

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit5

UserMapper.java

```java
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    public List<UserResponseDto> selectUserList();
    public void insertUser(UserSaveRequestDto userSaveRequestDto);

}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Long insertUser(UserSaveRequestDto userSaveRequestDto) {
        userMapper.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto);

        return userSaveRequestDto.getUserId();
    }

}
```

UserServiceTest.java

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    UserMapper userMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    // Mockito 이용한 테스트 코드
    @DisplayName("Mock을 사용한 insertUser 테스트")
    @Test
    public void insertUser() {
        // given
        UserSaveRequestDto userSaveRequestDto = UserSaveRequestDto.builder()
                .userName("test")
                .userPhoneNumber("01026137832")
                .build();

        willDoNothing().given(userMapper).insertUser(userSaveRequestDto);
        given(userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto)).willReturn(1L);

        // when
        Long userId = userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto);

        // then

        //mockito 스타일
        verify(userMapper).insertUser(userSaveRequestDto);

        //BDDMockito 스타일
        then(userMapper).should().insertUser(userSaveRequestDto);
        assertThat(userId).isEqualTo(1L);
    }
}
```

Exception

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue:
> 'insertUser' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a
> *return value*! Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
> doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod(); If you need to set the void method to do nothing you can use:
> doNothing().when(mock).someVoidMethod(); For more information, check out the javadocs for Mockito.doNothing().

---

If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:

1. The method you are trying to stub is *overloaded*. Make sure you are calling the right overloaded version.
2. Somewhere in your test you are stubbing *final methods*. Sorry, Mockito does not verify/stub final methods.
3. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies -

   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
4. Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
   at com.example.mybatis.user.UserServiceTest.insertUser(UserServiceTest.java:43)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)

I don't know why the test fails, please help me

Comment: Your test doesn't make sense (it isn't a Spring test but a mockito test, so why extend it with the spring runner). Next you are trying to register behavior on a non mock (your actually want to test the service, then why register behavior on it?).

Comment: It makes no sense for a _mapper_ to _insert_ a user.

Comment: what exactly isn't clear about this: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue: 'insertUser' is a void method and it cannot be stubbed with a return value! ?

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, i restored @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) But it still doesn't work.

Comment: You only read half of my comment... The crucial part is the fact that you are trying to register behavior on a non mock.

Comment: Sorry. @InjectMock was confused. But I have a question."given(userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto)).willReturn (1L);" Annotate this part and test is successful. But isn't it practically a mapper test? Is this a service layer test?

Comment: You are testing your service not the mapper. As you are mocking the mapper.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thank you so much... Happy New Year. M. Deinum

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to adopt the comments. Is there a way to adopt it?